# How to install python on Samsung S5600 halley EVO

Tags: python, mobile, jailbreak

I would like to know how to install python on Samsung S5600 Halley Evo. Do I have to do something like a jailbreak? Is it possible? and, if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is to download Android Scripting Environment, since I guess your Samsung is an Android phone. Within the ASE, you can determine which programming languages to use, weather its plain unix Shell, Python or Perl. Up to 10 different scripting languages are supported.

Jailbreaking is something you do on an iPhone, since its locked by Apple. The Android handheld device is not locked, so you can install all you want, without using the Android Market. You can even uninstall applications, like the built in Messaging app if you want to use Handcent SMS instead :)

Ref: [Android Scripting Environment](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)

Comment: thanks a lot! but i don't undestand how to install ASE...there are many scripts, wich i have to take?

Comment: Download the package to your computer and unzip, hook up your device through cable, move the .apk-file to where your other .apk-files are (I only know Samsung i7500) and your on the way. Restart - and you'll find the ASE among your other apps :)